# Why is Gio.Socket.create_source() returning null?

Tags: sockets, gio, gjs

I'm new to sockets and trying to work through some socket programming in GJS/Gio and hit a wall creating a GLib.Source to handle receiving from a socket. The relevant code (I think) is:

```
const DeviceChannel = new Lang.Class({
    Name: "DeviceChannel",

    _init: function (device) {
        this.device = device;

        this.connection = null;
        this.inStream = null;
        this.outStream = null;
        this.socket = null;
        this.sock_source = 0;
    },

    open: function () {
        let client = new Gio.SocketClient();

        this.addr = new Gio.InetSocketAddress({
            address: this.device.tcpHost,
            port: this.device.tcpPort
        });

        let conn = client.connect_async(
            this.addr,
            null,
            Lang.bind(this, this.opened)
        );
    },

    opened: function (client, res) {
        this.connection = client.connect_finish(res);

        // Streams
        this.inStream = new Gio.DataInputStream({
            base_stream: this.connection.get_input_stream()
        });

        this.outStream = new Gio.DataOutputStream({
            base_stream: this.connection.get_output_stream()
        });

        // Socket
        this.socket = this.connection.get_socket();
        this.socket.set_option(6, 4, 10);   // TCP_KEEPIDLE
        this.socket.set_option(6, 5, 5);    // TCP_KEEPINTVL
        this.socket.set_option(6, 6, 3);    // TCP_KEEPCNT
        this.socket.set_keepalive(true);

        this.sock_source = this.socket.create_source(GLib.IOCondition.IN, null);
        this.sock_source.set_callback(Lang.bind(this, this._io_ready));
        this.sock_source.attach(null);
    },

    _io_ready: function (condition) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

All goes well until I call `this.sock_source.set_callback()` when I get the error:

```
(JSConnect:15118): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError: this.sock_source is null
DeviceChannel<.opened@application.js:184:9
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/lang.js:178:22
@application.js:427:2
```

I have called `Gio.Socket.create_source()` on another socket (although UDP) in another part of the code which works fine. Calling `create_source()` itself doesn't throw any errors (even if I run my script with `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all`) and there is no mention of the function ever returning `null` [in the documentation](http://devdocs.baznga.org/gio20~2.50p/gio.socket#method-create_source) so I'm baffled as to what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:**

There is 3 year old comment [here](https://gist.github.com/maghul/4ddaa5879ef0ece5dbe3) that states:

> This does *not* work since 1)  Socket.create_source doesn't exist in
>   typelib as it is marked
>       with (skip) in Glib/gio/gsocket.c

But I *assume* this is no longer true since I have created a source on my UDP socket, although that socket is "hand-made" not built using `Gio.SocketClient()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably inadvertently calling the [`Gio.DatagramBased.create_source()`](http://devdocs.baznga.org/gio20~2.50p/gio.datagrambased#method-create_source) method. Looking at the source code, this will call `g_socket_create_source()` eventually, but does some checks first and returns `null` if those fail. Here are the checks: https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gsocket.c#L1114

It looks to be a minor bug that [the method will simply return `null`](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/gsocket.c#L1187) without even printing the error from `check_datagram_based()`.

Comment: The GJS docs say that `Gio.Socket` inherits `Gio.DatagramBased` so maybe this function is not being overridden by `Gio.Socket`? I've confirmed that the socket is TCP and STREAM by checking those properties. Or is there a different way to call this function I'm missing? I should say this code is copied almost verbatim from a Vala program for the same protocol.

Comment: The comment that you linked to above, that says `g_socket_create_source()` is marked non-introspectable, is still current. So there is no `g_socket_create_source()` method in GJS to override the DatagramBased method. (If there were, you could do `Gio.Socket.protoype.create_source.call(this.socket, GLib.IOCondition.IN, null)`.) I'm not sure why they marked it that way.

Comment: For now I've used a workaround by creating a `Gio.UnixInputStream` from the socket's file descriptor and creating a source on that. Should I file a bug for this?

Comment: If so, GIR or Gio?

Comment: I'm not really sure how these methods are even supposed to work, so I'm not sure what the answer is.

Comment: Fair enough, when I get a chance I'll just file a bug and let the maintainers take it from there.